# Hide smaller image portion, not overlapping with larger image in the background

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiimageview

[image]
 I have two images, one larger than the other. My need is to be able to drag and place the smaller image anywhere above the larger one. The problem is that, I don't want the portion of the smaller image outside the larger image's boundary to be seen. Once the smaller image's non-transparent portion stops overlapping the larger image non-transparent portion, the non-overlapping smaller image portion should be hidden.However, when the smaller image is completely inside the larger image's non-transparent portion, it should be visible.!

[For eg., the image shown consists of a larger image that is a T-shirt and a smaller image that is of a lady.I want to add the image of the lady over the T-shirt. It should be possible to move the image of the lady anywhere inside the T-shirt.And once the image of the lady moves out of the T-shirt's outer black boundary the non-overlapping portion of the image of the lady should become transparent. Here, the portion of the T-shirt image outside the black boundary is transparent.  Can someone help me with the code?

Comment: are you using pan gesture??

Comment: @ Saurabh Prajapati - yes

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is a pretty complex one. If the "T-Shirt" part is static than again it is easy for you to mark boundaries for that image. But if there is different background than you need to do more stuff.

Here you have to take a help of Core image. You need to process that image and get the core details of that image. Also **"Morphological Operations"** will help you to detect object from image. Take a look on links:

[Core image processing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro/ci_intro.html)

[Morphological Operations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/vImage/MorphologicalOperations/MorphologicalOperations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001001-CH212-SW2)

Also about the drag and drop follow this one.

[OBDragDrop](https://github.com/Oblong/OBDragDrop)